# Why does React.js remove younger siblings?

Tags: html, reactjs

Why does this code remove the `<div>Content After Hook</div>` element?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
   <span>React Content</span>,
   document.getElementById('react_hook')
   );
  </script>

  <div>Content Before Hook</div>

  <div id="react_hook"/>

  <div>Content After Hook</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are rendering react into react_hook, why would it touch the siblings? Besides not having an awareness of them and not having anything to do with them, it would also break websites that depend on those elements. React even give a warning if you use `document.body`, since you might unknowingly be wiping out elements not related to react.

Comment: Oops, the question was supposed to be "why **does** this code remove...". Edited to make the question make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot self-close `div` tags.

So it must be

```
<div id="react_hook"></div>
```

Your current layout is treated as opened and not closed `div` that contains everything up to `</body>`

References:

- [4.4.14 The div element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-div-element) (see the `Tag omission in text/html` section)